# How to attach a graph to a point feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, graph, identify

Is there any way to attach a graph to every point in a feature class?

When I click to identify a point in my map I want it to show me the characteristics from attribute table (as it actually shows) and a graph, unique of every point. These graphs are done in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display externally created graphs you could save them as images and and links to these files in the attribute table then either enable hyperlinks or configure the [html popup](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002r000000) to target them

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to [Enable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/enabling-attachments-on-a-feature-class.htm), [Add](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/adding-attachments-to-features.htm), and [View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/viewing-files-attached-to-features-attachments-.htm) attachments in the Attribute Table. The data is stored as a BLOB field I believe.

Or you can set the [HTML popup](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/setting-html-pop-up-properties-for-feature-layers.htm) properties as @whatahitson mentioned.